# Before consumers for new topic are attached, I create new topic and produce message in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Before consumers for new topic are attached, I create new topic and produce a first message in apache kafka.
Then consumers for new topic are attached, but the first message could not be consumed. 
Why..?

In this case, already log-end offset=1, commited offset=1, lag=0.

Doesn't "commited offset=1" mean it's already been consumed? 
My question is why it has already been consumed. 
Let me know if there's anything I'm wrong with.

This is my test case.

```
# create new topic 
$ kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic NEW_TOPIC_NAME

# produce a first message
$ kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic NEW_TOPIC_NAME
  > send a first message

# then execute consumer
$ kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic NEW_TOPIC_NAME
  >   # no consume a first message
```

But after consumers for new topic are attached, I produce a second message then normally consume.

Comment: The offset being 1 on the consumer does not mean that the message has been consumed. The offset indicates where in the topic the consumer will begin reading messages from.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `kafka-console-consumer` starts from the end of the topic.

If you want to consume messages produced before, you can set `--from-beginning` for example:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 
  --topic NEW_TOPIC_NAME --from-beginning
```

Comment: Doesn't "commited offset=1" mean it's already been consumed? My question is, there is no consumer, why has it been consumed? Let me know if there's anything I'm wrong with.